# Copying a mp3 File from a URL to server with php, no sound?

Tags: php, audio, upload, mp3, server

i am trying to save a mp3 file from a website "http...../filename.mp3" to my server from with the following php code, i receive the url in the $url from ajax. thats my code:

```
$url = $_POST['data'];
$filename = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);

$directory = './fileuploads/tmp/';

$data = file_get_contents($url);
$file = fopen($directory.$filename, "w+");
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

It works fine but the new mp3 file on my server is "empty". it doesnt play any sound. how do you guys would solve such a problem? please make it as simple as possible. best regards

Comment: Try reading up on curl and make an implementation with that which downloads your mp3: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: did you do any basic debugging, like `echo strlen($data)` to see if you actually received anything? You're simply assuming your url is always correct and that http requests never fail, and even assuming that the url is allowing itself to be scraped.

Comment: the file gets successfully created, it is just empty

Comment: Try to put some error checking in your code to see what the problem is. You likely aren't getting any data from the file on the remote server. But the way you have your code here it would still create a blank file regardless. If you put in some error checking you can find what the problem is, most likely that you aren't getting any data from the original file.